# How to group by in Pandas for subcategories?

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame which contains consumption data for the various building. The buildings are divided into few categories, further divided into subcategories. How could I return the count of the number of buildings of every subcategory itself?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two columns, called `col_1` and `col_2`. Then you can group by on the two of them by doing

`df.groupby(['col_1','col_2']).count()`

This would return the count for all the other columns in the database in the hierarchy specified by the columns `col_1` and `col_2`